# Equality with the Holder Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Im trying to show that when $f \in L^p(E)$ and $g \in L^q(E)$ where q is the conjugate of p then $\int_E|f\cdot g| = \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$ if and only if $\alpha |f|^p = \beta |g|^q$ for some $\alpha , \beta \not = 0$. I already showed the direction assuming the equality holds and I found that if equality is assumed then $\dfrac{|f|^p}{\|f\|_p^p} = \dfrac{|g|^q}{\|g\|_q^q} $. Im having trouble showing the other direction. Do I assume that $\dfrac{|f|^p}{\|f\|_p^p} = \dfrac{|g|^q}{\|g\|_q^q} $ and work with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_E|fg|= \int_E(|f|^p)^{1/p}|g| = \int_E(\frac{|g|^q}{||g||_q^q}||f||_p^p)^{1/p}|g| = \int_E||f||_p|g|^{q/p + 1}\frac{1}{||g||_q^{q/p}} = \frac{||f||_p}{||g||_q^{q/p}}\int_E|g|^q = \frac{||f||_p}{||g||_q^{q/p}}||g||^q =||f||_p||g||_q$$